# Heroku - Redirect console output to Logentries

Tags: bash, postgresql, heroku, casperjs

How do I redirect console output of Heroku's bash to Logentries / other file log?

I use the following commands:

```
heroku run bash
```

use the following command to run a long-running CasperJS script:

```
casperjs myscript.js
```

Then a lot of output appears in the console. How do I redirect the console output to a file / Logentries / PostgreSQL or other things that I can export to other server?

Comment: How are you connected? ssh?

Comment: `heroku run bash` in Terminal (btw, I'm using Mac OS X 10.10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try it with (at the local machine):

```
heroku run casperjs /path/to/myscript.js > log.txt
```

`log.txt` is then created on the local machine and the output is redirected there.

Comment: Question: will the script run in heroku / my local machine then ?

Comment: @Raptor no the script runs on the server but the outout is redirected to the local file `log.txt`

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is to use the following command:

```
casperjs myscript.js > log.txt
```

*( but how to retrieve the log.txt to local machine? )*